# Sum XML Value based on different attribute types

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-sql

I'm trying to extract number of adults, children and infants from the below example XML:

- Adults = AgeType 3
- Children = AgeType 2
- Infants = AgeType 1

and then count specifies how many of that age type. Correct result is:

- 35 Adults
- 5 Children
- 2 Infants

The below code returns the correct result, however I would like to avoid the `cross apply` entering to the `<Customer>` tags (as there are hundreds of millions per day).

```
declare @a table(a xml)
insert into @a  
select '<Customers>
        <Customer AgeType="3" Count="10" />    
        <Customer AgeType="3" Count="20" />
        <Customer AgeType="3" Count="5" />       
        <Customer AgeType="2" Count="5" />
        <Customer AgeType="1" Count="2" />
        </Customers>'

select  
    sum(case when b.cust = 3 then b.cust*b.count_cust end)/3 as adt
    ,sum(case when b.cust = 2 then b.cust*b.count_cust end)/2 as chd
    ,sum(case when b.cust = 1 then b.cust*b.count_cust end)/1 as inf
from   (
select c.value('(@AgeType)','int') As cust
,c.value('(@Count)','int') As count_cust
from @a cross apply a.nodes('Customers/Customer') as t(c)
) as b
```

Can anyone find any other logic that could be more effiecient? I was thinking using `count` or `sum` over the `<Customer>` tags like below, however I can't get the correct reults.

```
 a.value('count(Customers/Customer/@AgeType[.=3])','int') As adt
,a.value('count(Customers/Customer/@AgeType[.=2])','int') As chd
,a.value('count(Customers/Customer/@AgeType[.=1])','int') As inf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XPath from

```
count(Customers/Customer/@AgeType[.=3])
```

to

```
sum(Customers/Customer[@AgeType = 3]/@Count)
```

to sum up all adult (`@AgeType` = 3) `Customer` `@Count` attribute values.

Follow the same pattern for the other age types.

Comment: Hi, works as expected. i only had to change count(Customers/Customer[@AgeType = 3]/@Count) to use sum instead sum(Customers/Customer[@AgeType = 3]/@Count)

Comment: @DC07: Oh, yes, of course.  Sorry about that, and thanks for fixing it.